# How to hint that function checks if variable is undefined?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have two validator functions:

```js
export const isDefined = (something: any): boolean => {
  return something !== null && something !== undefined
}

export const isPositiveInteger = (something: any): boolean => {
  return isDefined(something) && Number.isInteger(something) && something >= 0
}
```

When I come to use these functions, TypeScript doesn't seem to detect that `isDefined` is ensuring that the variable cannot be null/undefined. For example:

```js
if (isDefined(filters) && isPositiveInteger(filters.page)) {
                                            ^ TS Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'
  ...
}
```

If I manually check in-line:

```js
if (filters !== undefined && filters !== nul && isPositiveInteger(filters.page)) {
                                                                  ^ No complaints from TS!
  ...
}
```

Is there some typing I can apply to the `isDefined` function that will make TypeScript understand that the variable passed in will always be defined if true is returned?

I understand that I can simply use the `?` flag, e.g. `filters?.page` but I would rather know if there was a more clean solution than having to constantly use this flag throughout this code block.

Comment: See this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think the example you posted is almost there - but how would I then type that the return type of the function is `boolean`, because in place of that I now have `something is T`. Thanks again

Comment: `something is T` **is** a boolean, it just has additional information packed in it (from a type perspective).